# Date and time zone on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, timezone, date

I ran the `date` command and it gave the following output:

```
root@localhost:~$ date
Thu Dec 30 14:19:47 UTC 2010
```

Then, I modified the date using `date -s` which gave the following output:

```
root@localhost:~$ date -s "12/30/2010 JST 14:19:47"
Thu Dec 30 05:19:47 UTC 2010
```

I noticed that the time changed to 9 hours behind UTC to show exactly the JST time. But the time zone, as you can see, is still UTC. Why is it showing the correct time and incorrect time zone?

Answer (score 9):

This is because your system is set to use UTC (or has no time zone set) and not JST. The date command will accept JST as an input modifier but then uses the system default to display it. If you want your system to display the time in JST format then you should set the time zone to JST.

Remove or rename `/etc/localtime` and then link the relevant file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` to `/etc/localtime`:

```
cd /etc
mv localtime localtime.orig
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime
```

Edit:

To answer your comment - The date command has to be able to understand time zone information provided as part of the `date string` parameter of `-s` and what to do with it. If you examine the [source code](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) you will find that all of the common time zone abbreviations, and their offsets from GMT are defined. This information is then used to set the time correctly. Depending on the version of core-utils you examine, you'll find the information in `lib/parse-datetime.c` or `lib/getdate.c`.

Comment: Thanks Iain :)...But when i gave JST as the timezone in the date -s command, the time decreased by 9 hours. From where does the system find out to decrease exactly 9 hours when JST is give as the input of date -s command?

Comment: Timezone information is under /usr/share/zoneinfo, at least for Fedora.

Comment: I do not have the timezone package installed. Still when i simply execute the command `date -s "12/30/2010 JST 14:19:47"`, the time is exactly the time of Japan, 9 hours behind UTC, although the timezone is not changing in the output. I want to know, how `date` decreases exactly 9 hours even though there is no timezone package installed.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: See my edit for more information

Answer (score 1):

Just set your timezone properly and then you will be able to use the date command "naturally".

```
export TZ=JST
```

Comment: I don't think "JST" is a valid time zone identifier for the `TZ` variable. Running `TZ=JST date +"%z %Z"` shows a UTC offset of +0000 which doesn't match the +0900 offset of Japan Standard Time. On the other hand, `TZ=":Asia/Tokyo" date +"%z %Z"` seems to work. See also `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, Wikipedia on the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), and [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-can-i-have-date-output-the-time-from-a-different-time-zone) on setting a time zone for `date`.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun I had the impression the [`JST` timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Standard_Time) was known by the OP system 13 years ago but you are definitely right using `Asia/Tokyo` would be the way to go.